# duvida função javascript

Tags: php, javascript

tenho uma pagina com uma tabela e dados vindo do banco, essa pagina possui refresh automático, os dados estão vindo de outra pagina (getdados.php), essa tabela possui uma coluna chamada status, que por default quando e inserido no BD ela vai como disponível, nesta mesma coluna adicionei um botão pra mudar o status para: pendente e recolhido, mas a minha função javascript não esta funcionando, o que ha de errado?

## arquivo getdados.php

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#sel1').on('change', function(){
              var selecionado = $('#sel1').val();
          $.ajax({
           data: 'selecionado='+selecionado,
          type: 'post',
         url: 'status.php', 
         });
     });
 });
```

```
<?php
//Conectando ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tcc");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

//Consultando banco de dados
$qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM postagens");    
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
?>
<table id='tabela'>
<tr>
<td><?= $r['id'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['nome'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['rua'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['bairro'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['telefone'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['descricao'] ?></td>     
<td>
<select id='sel1'>
<option value='status'><?= $r['status'] ?></option>
<option value='pendente'>Pendente</option>
<option value='recolhido'>Recolhido</option>
</select></td>
</table>

<?php 
   } 
?>
```

## arquivo status.php

```
   <?php
    include_once("setting.php");
   $escolha = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'selecionado');

   if($escolha === 'recolhido'){
    $sql = "UPDATE postagens  SET status = $escolha'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
    echo $linhas;
    if ($linhas ==1){   
    echo "sucesso";
        }else{
            echo "erro";
        }   

  }else{           

   }

?>
```

Comment: Chega a chamar a url, status.php? Cara acho que falta um `WHERE`, no seu SQL, não é isso que está fazendo deixar de funcionar, mas do jeito que tá vai fazer update na sua tabela toda.

Comment: sim chamei ele no getdados.php, onde coloco a funçao? no arquivo que esta a tabela? ou no getdados msm?

Comment: Defina "não está funcionando". O que acontece? Dá erro ? Confirme no inspecionar do navegador. Se sim qual o erro que aparece ? Aproveite e confirme também no separador de rede do inspecionar se os pedidos estão a ser feitos e quais os dados que tem neles.

Comment: nao esta mudando o status no banco, minha duvida e o seguinte, gostaria apenas de saber se a função esta certa, se estou passando o valor corretamente para a função, se eu tenho que passar o id do registro que vou mudar, como que eu passo para a função.

Answer (score 0):

Sua função javascript esta correta. Você precisa enviar um id para atualizar somente aquele registro no banco.

**getdados.php**

```
<?php
//Conectando ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tcc");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

//Consultando banco de dados
$qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM postagens");    
?>
<table id='tabela'>
    <?php while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $r['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['nome'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['rua'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['bairro'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['telefone'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $r['descricao'] ?></td>     
            <td>
                <select class="sel" data-id='<?= $r['id'] ?>'>
                    <option value='status'><?= $r['status'] ?></option>
                    <option value='pendente'>Pendente</option>
                    <option value='recolhido'>Recolhido</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php }  ?>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sel').on('change', function () {
        var selecionado = $(this).val(); 
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            data: "id="+ id +"&selecionado=" + selecionado,
            type: 'post',
            url: 'status.php',
        });
    });
});
```

**status.php**

```
    if($escolha === 'recolhido'){
        $sql = "UPDATE `postagens` SET `status` = '$escolha' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
                    // ^ Sempre faça o escape para você não ter problemas com variáveis internas.
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
        echo $linhas;
        if ($linhas == 1){   
            echo "sucesso";
        }else{
            echo "erro";
        }   

    }else{           

    }
?>
```

Na sua query original, você tem apenas uma ' `[...]status = $escolha'`, `status` é uma palavra reservada também. o certo seria `` [...] `status` = '$escolha' ``

Comment: quando passo o mouse sobre o option console retorna seguinte erro: [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Comment: Você ta usando alguma framework alem do jQuery para javascript? outra coisa tbm, vc não pode usar `<select id='sel1'>` porque `id` tem que ser um valor único em sua página html

Comment: estou usando o bootstrap, então como faço para passar o dado do botão para o evento javascript de outra pagina?